# Chart values is rounded when present on mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

This is my list of my BarEntry On `MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3` 
[image]

as you can see its values on 3 index of array. My question is why when these values shows on chart their values is rounded ?
[image]

this my codes:

```
 barEntriesCur.add(new BarEntry(1, (float) Double.parseDouble(incomeModel.getIncome_Payable_Cur()) / 1000000));
 barEntriesCur.add(new BarEntry(2, (float) Double.parseDouble(incomeModel.getNosazi_Payable_Cur()) / 1000000));
 barEntriesCur.add(new BarEntry(3, (float) Double.parseDouble(incomeModel.getSenfi_Payable_Cur()) / 1000000));

 barEntriesPre.add(new BarEntry(1, (float) Double.parseDouble(incomeModel.getIncome_Payable_Pre()) / 1000000));
 barEntriesPre.add(new BarEntry(2, (float) Double.parseDouble(incomeModel.getNosazi_Payable_Pre()) / 1000000));
 barEntriesPre.add(new BarEntry(3, (float) Double.parseDouble(incomeModel.getSenfi_Payable_Pre()) / 1000000));


BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntriesCur, "cur");
barDataSet.setColors(AXisValueFormatter.SAFACUSTOM_COLORS2);
BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(barEntriesPre, "pre");
barDataSet1.setColors(AXisValueFormatter.SAFACUSTOM_COLORS3);
BarData data = new BarData(barDataSet, barDataSet1);
mBinding.barChartReport.setData(data);
float groupSpace = 0.20f;
float barSpace = 0.02f;
float barWidth = 0.35f;
data.setBarWidth(barWidth);
data.setValueTextSize(10f);
mBinding.barChartReport.groupBars(1, groupSpace, barSpace);

mBinding.barChartReport.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(true);
mBinding.barChartReport.setPinchZoom(false);
mBinding.barChartReport.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
mBinding.barChartReport.setDrawGridBackground(false);
mBinding.barChartReport.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
mBinding.barChartReport.setFitBars(true);
mBinding.barChartReport.invalidate();
```

Comment: try to add 
`barDataSet.setValueFormatter(new DefaultValueFormatter(3)); // round to three digits`

Comment: I do but if last number was digit except `0` this number is rounded.Example your code work this way: 771.619968 -> 77.162 @Subzero

Comment: Why the last number  is rounded ?? I need an exact number

Comment: try this

`        barDataSet.setValueFormatter(new IValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
                return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s", value);
            }
        });
`

Comment: @Subzero number is rounded again  https://imgur.com/DinONpu   . this is original image https://ibb.co/iiWpsT

Comment: @sayreskabir please see my answer below. I've tested it with your code and it does the thing

Comment: Ok dude,I'll try your code and announce you. @MishaAkopov

Answer (score 2):

Implemented your code and here is solution. 
But first explanation:
This happens because values are in big range, you have 5595 and 590 on the same Graph, so default value formatter removes decimals, because it thinks it is not important.

Solution is to implement your custom formatter:

```
public class MyDecimalValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }
    }
```

And then set it to dataset:

```
data.setValueFormatter(new MyDecimalValueFormatter());
```

Tested with your code and it works (with your data):

[image]